# how to define char(2) column in hibernate hbm.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi must modify some hibernate legacy code and I should define a SQL char(2) column (foreign key to a char(2) primary key).

My definition file contains:

```
    <property
        name="language"
        type="char"
        update="true"
        insert="true"
        column="LANGUAGE"
        length="2"
    />
```

but hibernate generates:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
(...)
| LANGUAGE            | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |    
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The foreign key table is something like:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| LANGUAGE     | char(2)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
(...)
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: there is nothing like char(2) in java, you meant String? and sql you meant varchar(2), your hibernate type should be string. or am i missing something?

Comment: @sakura `varchar(2)` is variable length with max 2. `char(2)` is fixed length.

Comment: @sakura the referenced table is created with:

`CREATE TABLE languages (
  LANGUAGE char(2) NOT NULL,
  LABEL varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  LOCALE varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  POSITION int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ENABLED tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (LANGUAGE)
)`

Comment: got solution for your problem check [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=956019) .. oh one answer also came from @JasonC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `char` type in Hibernate does not map to a `String`, it maps to a `char` or `Character` in Java (see [6.1.1.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic)). It happens to use `char(1)` as the underlying column type in the table to support this for your DBMS; which by coincidence makes it *seem* like it's simply ignoring the length (but its reasons are actually unrelated).

You'll have to use `string` for the type (so it maps to a Java `String`), then you'll have to tell it to use `char(2)` for storage. One option is to explicitly specify `sql-type`, e.g.:

```
<property name="language" type="string" update="true" insert="true">
    <column name="LANGUAGE" sql-type="char(2)"/>
</property>
```

Or just manually adjust the table afterwards to change it from `varchar(2)` to `char(2)`.

Comment: (I believe you can also use `sql-type="char" length="2"` in the `column` instead of `sql-type="char(2)"`, but it's been a while and I can't easily test it right now.)